# Runtime Error - Toggle Button

Tags: excel, vba

so I'm writing a basic script and the toggle button keeps giving me a runtime error when I select the macro. Basically, what I want it to do is toggle the calculations Manuel off and on, because there is a ton of formulas and when new data is entered, the auto updating takes forever and its become a hassle which is why I wanted to use this. It has worked in the past but now for some reason it is not working. I am kind of new to this and any information will help.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Worksheets("Schedule").CommandButton1.Caption = "Auto Calc: ON" & Chr(10) & "[Click to Toggle]"
ClacState = False


End Sub
```

Comment: What does the run-time error actually say?

Comment: `ClacState` looks like it's misspelled. The compiler can automatically catch errors like this if you use `Option Explicit`

Comment: What is `ClacState`? I merely know about [Application.CalculationState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196047.aspx).

Comment: the only thing that is highlighted is the row "worksheets("schedule").Commandbutton1...etc etc

Comment: What is the error number?

Comment: Check the name of the worksheet and command button are correct.  If someone changed the name of either then that is your problem.  Also check that your button is actually a button and not a Shape.

Comment: @DavidCram Are you aware that you actually proposed in your comment the very same I posted in my solution (just 5 minutes later)?

Comment: Nope.  I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: object doesn't support this property or method - run time error '438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following (more verbose) code you should be able to identify the problem:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Obj As OLEObject
Dim bolFound As Boolean
Dim ClacState As Boolean

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

'Verify that the sheet exists
bolFound = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Schedule" Then bolFound = True
Next ws
If bolFound = False Then
    MsgBox "The is no such sheet `Schedule`." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
    Exit Sub
End If

'Verify that there is a button by that name
bolFound = False
For Each Obj In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Schedule").OLEObjects
    If Obj.Name = "CommandButton1" And TypeName(Obj.Object) = "CommandButton" Then bolFound = True
Next Obj
If bolFound = False Then
    MsgBox "The is no such button `CommandButton1` on the sheet `Schedule`." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
    Exit Sub
End If

Worksheets("Schedule").CommandButton1.Caption = "Auto Calc: ON" & Chr(10) & "[Click to Toggle]"

End Sub
```